# Laptop constantly making device/USB unplugged sound randomly

Tags: laptop, usb, windows-8.1

My Laptop constantly making USB disconnected sound at completely random amount times but the strange thing is it doesn't make USB plugged sound and 2 of my devices that are cooling fan(doesn't make any sound when plugged or unplugged) and mouse still working when the USB unplugged sound is made although I do noticed the mouse lagged for less than a sec when the sound is made but when this problem happened while I was playing a game (Dota2) my laptop screen will freeze for about 3sec, so what caused my laptop randomly make the USB unplugged sound?

Laptop model and specs:

- Acer Aspire E1-472G
- INTEL CORE i5-4200U 1.6GHz (Turbo boost up to 2.6GHz)
- 4GB DDR3 RAM
- NVIDIA GeForce 820M(2GM)

Comment: Any USB device that consumes power but does not report it's presence on the bus (as in making that connect/disconnect sound) is in violation of the USB spec.  The computer can't tell you how much power is being used, only how much each device claims is being used.  Too much power draw can trip a port reset and the behavior you describe.  The cooling fan is the most likely cause, unplug it before it damages your computer permanently.  That's assuming this hasn't been resolved by now.  Can someone accept an answer, or something, so the system doesn't keep bumping this question?

Answer (score 1):

Some of the most common reasons for the random disconnect sounds are:

- A device is either pulling too much power.  Once the device pulls too much power, the USB controller shuts the port down for safety
- Too many devices are pulling power and the USB controller shuts down a port for safety
- A loose connection

Unplug all your USB devices and test them individually for a decent amount of time.  Does any one device cause the issue?  If not, add devices one at a time and check.  Repeat the process until the you have an issue.

Comment: Is there a way to tell if a USB device is drawing too much power?

Comment: "Is there a way to tell if a USB device is drawing too much power? "  There's the option to get a USB power meter, which might not cost much but isn't free either.  There's trial and error, which costs no money but time consuming and not fool proof.

Comment: @MacGuffin It will show up in the Windows event log, if it is an onboard USB controller

Comment: @Keltari The actual power draw will not show in the Windows event log because the devices might not report how much power they draw, or might report it incorrectly.  This is unfortunately quite common, making the OS logs unreliable.  The question stated the cooling fan made no indication of being connected, this tells me the device is not reporting how much power it draws to the OS.  There isn't an actual power meter on USB ports, they trust that the devices will report power draw accurately.  This trust is often broken.

Comment: @MacGuffin It will, Oh it will.  I dont remember the event ID, but there is a Windows [error](https://superuser.com/questions/1350148/how-to-fix-the-unknown-usb-device-needs-more-power-than-the-port-can-supply-er) associated with it.

Comment: @Keltari  No, that Windows error is not indicating the actual power draw.  That error shows when a device *requests* more power than is available, if a misbehaving device *takes* that power without asking then the error will not show.  In some cases the fuses on the port open the circuit and reset, sometimes the voltage drops and devices start acting funny, if it's really bad then you can see things like the computer shutting down or the magic smoke coming out.

Answer (score 0):

**only two specific reasons are:**
1 Cooling Pad:

it uses USB Power, in other words there are four terminal in USB Interface 2 for Voltages and 2 for Data. so you cooling Fan is Using Voltages not data. but sometime it happen (Might be Due to poor manufacturing) that Cooling Pad try to connect with PC. i.e trying to use other 2 terminals that are Data. if so it tries to connect and then disconnect. therefore your PC made Plugin & Unplug sounds.

**2:USB ports are Loose:**

When USB terminal get loose (Due to mishandling). it show frequent disconnection of devices.

**My Suggestion:**
Figure out which device causing this. Cooling Pad or Other device. by Plugging one device at a time.

Or you can remove and reinstall USB device driver in Device Manager. You can go there by right clicking **My Computer** and selecting **"Manage"** and then Selecting **"Device Manager"** and in Devices List remove **"Universal Serial Bus Controller"**